# self::STAT in yii relations

Tags: php, yii

i cant understand what is meant by this in yii framework

In the activity model i have this.

```
'registeredCount'=>array(self::STAT, 'ActivityParticipant', 'activities_id'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is just a statistical query and it will simply count all related `ActivityParticipant`.

You should read this :

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at CActiveFinder and I am not sure whether self::STAT always uses a separate query or not.
It looks like it also tries to do a LEFT JOIN ... GROUP BY sometimes.
Actually that's one of the reasons I hardly use it.